# Why am I getting an exception InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have written the following code which removes the selected value from the listBox. I also want to remove it from the Dictionary List and then update/write it to the text file so when I run the program again and load the text file it will be updated if not it will keep showing the removed item each time I run my application again.

```
private void listBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            string sb;
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                if (this.listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                {
                    string obj = this.listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    data.Remove(obj);
                    listBox1.DataSource = null;
                    listBox1.DataSource = data;
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in LocalyKeyWords)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < kvp.Value.Count(); i++)
                        {
                            sb = "Url: " + kvp.Key + " --- " + "Local KeyWord: " + kvp.Value[i] + Environment.NewLine;
                            LocalyKeyWords.Remove(kvp.Key);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

LocalyKeyWords is a Dictionary>

In this case it contain two items/keys I remove one and I see with a breakpoint that this one have been removed.

The question is if I need to remove the kvp.Key or to remove somehow the item I removed from the listBox wich is the one I want to remove from the LocalyKeywords and it's the obj variable since im doing:

```
data.Remove(obj);
```

So maybe I need to remove obj also from the localyKeyWords ?

The excpetion the error im getting is after it's removing the item from the LocalyKeyWords an click continue on this line:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp in LocalyKeyWords)
```

Im getting the error:

Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Enumerator.MoveNext()
       at GatherLinks.Form1.listBox1_KeyDown(Object sender, KeyEventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Form1.cs:line 959
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessKeyMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKeyChar(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at GatherLinks.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Your two for loops have no sense. You loop over the keys of the dictionary, then you loop over the items in the list and try to remove the key of the dictionary for each element in the list. Something is very wrong here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are removing items from `LocalyKeyWords` while in the midst of iterating over it; that is not allowed, as the exception message says.

I 'm not sure what the big picture is here, but a localized solution would be to make a temporary copy of `LocalyKeyWords` and iterate over that. You can then modify the "source" collection without any trouble.

Example:

```
foreach (var kvp in LocalyKeyWords.ToList())  // .ToList() makes a temp copy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the IEnumerable collection inside of `foreach`.

You can create a copy of the dictionary and loop through it modifing the original one.